# Href Link Beyond Group

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

Below is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=white,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\newcommand\JRNL[1]{#1}
\newcommand\AUGRP[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand\AUTHOR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SNM[1]{#1}
\newcommand\INITS[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SEP[1]{#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\ATITLE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\JTITLE[1]{{\em #1}}
\newcommand\VOLUME[1]{#1}
\newcommand\YEAR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\FPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\LPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\REFDOI[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\JRNL{
\bibitem{bib1}
\AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
\ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
\JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
\VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
\FPAGE{1177}\SEP{ (}
\YEAR{1996}\SEP{). }
\REFDOI{https://www.google.com}\SEP{.}
}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

My problem is to display HREF link combined for the below

```
\VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
\FPAGE{1177}\SEP{ (}
\YEAR{1996}\SEP{).}
```

and not in \REFDOI{} tag

But i don't want to add/Interchange extra tags/Commands in my reference structure,

Here with attached the required output,

[image]

Please guide, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you *always* have a `\VOLUME`...`\REFDOI` input?

Answer (score 3):

The following redefinition of `\JRNL` helps track the existence of `\REFDOI`, and accordingly redefines `\VOLUME` to capture its argument(s) for placement in a hyperlink:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=white,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\newcommand\JRNL[1]{%
  \def\JRNLarg{#1}% Store argument in \JRNLarg
  % Check whether \JNRLarg contains \REFDOI or not
  \patchcmd{\JRNLarg}{\REFDOI}{\REFDOI}{% \REFDOI found
    \gdef\VOLUME##1##2\REFDOI##3\SEP##4{{%
      \def\YEAR####1\SEP####2{####1\SEP{####2}\unskip}%
      \href{##3}{##1##2}%
    }}%
  }{% \REFDOI not found
    \gdef\VOLUME##1{##1}%
  }%
  #1% Process argument
  }
\newcommand\AUGRP[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand\AUTHOR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SNM[1]{#1}
\newcommand\INITS[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SEP[1]{#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\ATITLE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\JTITLE[1]{\emph{#1}}
\newcommand\YEAR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\FPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\LPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\REFDOI[1]{\href{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\JRNL{
  \bibitem{bib1}
  \AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
  \ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
  \JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
  \VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
  \FPAGE{1177}\SEP{ (}
  \YEAR{1996}\SEP{). }
  \REFDOI{https://www.google.com}\SEP{.}
}

\JRNL{
  \bibitem{bib2}
  \AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
  \ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
  \JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
  \VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
  \FPAGE{1177}\SEP{.}
  \REFDOI{https://www.google.com}\SEP{.}
}

\JRNL{
  \bibitem{bib3}
  \AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
  \ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
  \JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
  \FPAGE{1177}\SEP{. }
  \REFDOI{https://www.google.com}\SEP{.}
}

\JRNL{
  \bibitem{bib3}
  \AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
  \ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
  \JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
  \VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
  \FPAGE{1177}\SEP{.}
}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes \JRNL entries will have \VOLUME without a \REFDOI, thanks for your advice and the answer

Comment: @user52124: I've updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

```
\REFDOI[https://www.google.com]{%
\VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
\FPAGE{1177}\SEP{ (}
\YEAR{1996}\SEP{). }
}
}
```

with

```
\newcommand\REFDOI[2][]{\href{#1}{#2}}
```

works but where and when it may break depends on your luck.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,%
    citecolor=white,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\newcommand\JRNL[1]{#1}
\newcommand\AUGRP[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand\AUTHOR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SNM[1]{#1}
\newcommand\INITS[1]{#1}
\newcommand\SEP[1]{#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\ATITLE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\JTITLE[1]{{\em #1}}
\newcommand\VOLUME[1]{#1}
\newcommand\YEAR[1]{#1}
\newcommand\FPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\LPAGE[1]{#1}
\newcommand\REFDOI[2][]{\href{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\JRNL{
\bibitem{bib1}
\AUGRP{\AUTHOR{\INITS{L.}\SEP{ }\SNM{Snselfin}}}\SEP{. }
\ATITLE{Simple Text title.}\SEP{ }
\JTITLE{Regfionfal swqfq}\SEP{ }
\REFDOI[https://www.google.com]{%
\VOLUME{26}\SEP{, }
\FPAGE{1177}\SEP{ (}
\YEAR{1996}\SEP{). }
}
}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually i don't want to Enclose the commands inside \REFDOI, wanted to do it through definitions, the \REFdoi should stay in its same place

Comment: I dont want to interchange my Tags as you did in \REFDOI after \VOLUME{}, is that possible, please guide me